# Чем отличаются vim-gnome, vim-tiny, vim-gtk, vim-nox?

Tags: ubuntu, vim

У меня в системе по умолчанию не стоит vim. Какой пакет стоит поставить?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Суффиксы -gnome, -qt, -nox, -gtk означают графические библиотеки и/или среду, под которую написана программа.

- -gtk - с использованием библиотеки GTK,
- -qt - с использованием библиотеки QT,
- -gnome - почти наверняка под графическую оболочку GNOME и почти наверняка с использованием GTK,
- -nox - версия для использование без графического интерфейса из консоли,
- -tiny - как уже сказано выше, просто урезанная версия, облегченная, скажем.

PS:

> У меня в системе по умолчанию не стоит vim. Какой пакет стоит поставить?

Можно поставить все сразу. По идее конфликтовать не должны.

Answer (score 13):

Если нужна поддержка буфера обмена Х11 при работе в окне терминала, надо поставить
пакет, скомпилированный с библиотеками для буфера обмена. Графический gVim всегда его поддерживает.

Поддерживается ли этот буфер:

```
vim --version | grep clipboard
```

Если `+clipboard` или `+xterm_clipboard`, всё в порядке.
Если нет (т.е. `-` вместо `+`), то на Debian и Ubuntu надо поставить vim-gtk или vim-gnome.

Если поддержка буфера обмена не нужна, поставьте vim-nox.

На заметку: кто привык работать в терминале, тому непривычно копи+паста с нажатым шифт, попробуйте перенаправлять содержимое визуального выделения сразу в клипборд:

```
set clipboard=autoselect,unnamed,exclude:cons\|linux
```

Comment: Спасибо за клипбоард: `vim-gnome` с Xubuntu 16.04 работает, а `vim-gtk` что-то не пошёл.

Comment: Странно, вроде оба должны. У меня debian-gnome и что-то тоже не идёт. Пока времени не было разобраться, копи-пасте по старинке - с мизинцем на шифте

Comment: Так `Ctrl+Shift+C` работает только когда мышкой выделяешь, а когда через визуальный режим (например, при выделении строк: `V`), то это не работает ... Или это только у меня так?..

Answer (score 8):

`vim-tiny` - урезанная версия. `vim-nox` - расширенная версия. Остальные включают графический интерфейс. Если нужен функциональный редактор без графики стоит поставить `vim-nox`.